Como puedo generar errores en mi API con Express y mariadb?
Estoy trabajando en un API con express y mariadb que tiene la siguiente funcion en el endPoint de login:
export async function login(data){
    const {identification, password} = data
    let connection
    try{
        connection = await db.getConnection()
        const user = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE identification = ?', [identification])
        console.log(user)
        if(user.length == 0){
            throw new Error('No se ah encontrado el usuario')
        }else if(user.password != password){
            throw new Error('Contraseña incorrecta')
        }else{
            return user
        }
    }catch(err){
        return err
    }finally{
        if(connection)connection.release()
    }
}

antes trabajando con SQLite si el usuario no existia me retornaba undefined pero mariadb me esta retornando algunas veces un array vacio y otras un objeto vacio o un string vacio, cual seria la forma correcta de manejar un usuario no encontrado?

identification es un valor requerido? el unico motivo que se me ocurre para que devuelva 3 tipos de datos diferentes es que esa variable no siempre sea del mismo tipo de dato
